# How to define range in "for" at Django template

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

Django ListView returns object_list, and in Template I want to take the data only once using "for".

So I wrote this code.

> {% for item in object_list(range(1)) %}

But this code does not work. Here is the error code.

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '(range(1))' from 'object_list(range(1))'
```

I know my for code is something wrong, please teach me how to write properly.

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not define this in the template, but in the view. The view thus looks like:

```
def my_view(request):
    context = {
        'myrange': range(1),
        # …
    }
    return render(request, 'some-template.html', context)
```

and then enumerate with:

```
{% for item in myrange %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```